# Are the Azure usage and rate card APIs supported for US GOV EA subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api, azure-gov

I have a client with a Azure subscription sitting in a US GOV data center.  This subscription is under an EA (not pay-as-you-go).

Attempting to use the standard billing APIs (ratecard and usage) fails with a 'Subscription not found' error.  I.e. running the following:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[subscription id here]/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-USGOV-0017P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'
```

fails with:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "SubscriptionNotFound",
        "message": "The subscription '[subscription id here]' could not be found."
    }
}
```

I've found very little information on the rate card and usage APIs with EA accounts and even less information on these APIs for accounts running in a US GOV Azure region.  Does anyone know if this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with the Gov environment, but otherwise my experience is that Resource Usage API also works for EA, whereas the RateCard does not.
I would suggest you to start out with the powershell cmdlets for an easy start
* *Get-AzureRmUsage*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.insights/v2.3.0/get-azurermusage

Be sure that you have powershell running correctly towards the Government environment first. 
If you want to roll your own client remember to use the correct endpoints as described in "Azure Government developer guide"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government-developer-guide

Brgds Brian

Comment: I think Brian is spot on: The usage API can be made to work (though for gov data centers the Url is https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net and not https://management.azure.com).  As for the rate card API, it appears you are out of luck with EA accounts.  This means it is not possible to obtain cost information for EA accounts using the usage and billing API.  The solution, I think, is to use the custom billing API for EAs.  See [here](http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=631) for details.

Comment: @Greg thx, is this still true a year later?
Going to investigated the Custom Billing API you reference for rate card access.

Answer (score 0):

For EA offer IDs, you need to use the following API:

> https://consumption.azure.com/v2/enrollments/(enrollment_id)/pricesheet

You will need to provide EA API Key (different than bearer token from other APIs):

> curl -X GET   https://consumption.azure.com/v2/enrollments/(enrollment_id)/pricesheet   -H 'authorization: Bearer (api_key)'

Note that the API bearer token needs to be created in the EA Portal under the User Account.  More detail can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-enterprise-api

Also note that the user must have appropriate privileges otherwise the API will reject your request.